# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near "...dataSource.map...")

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render the API data onto the page but get this error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near "...dataSource.map...")

Unrelated Question: Also I am new to mobile app development and am wondering when you get data from an API is best practice to store it in a database or render it directly onto a page?

```
    import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
    import { ScreenContainer } from "react-native-screens";

    export const Home = () => {
      const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);
      const [dataSource, setdataSource] = useState(null);

      useEffect(async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        const movies = data.title;
        setdataSource(movies);
        setisLoading(false);

        // .catch((error)) => {
        //   console.log(error)
        // }
      }, []);


      if (isLoading) {
        return (
          <View>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      } else {
        let moviest = dataSource.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <View key={key}>
              <Text>{val}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        });

        return (
          <ScreenContainer style={styles.container}>
            <View>{moviest}</View>
          </ScreenContainer>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to check `dataSource` is null or undefined before `map`.

`let moviest = dataSource && dataSource.map((val, key) => {`

Answer (score 0):

Please check type of `dataSource`.

When I check `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json` data, type of `data.title` is string("The Basics - Networking")

Maybe you should use `movies`.

```js
const data = await response.json();
const movies = data.movies;
setdataSource(movies);
setisLoading(false);
```